# Ошибка "имя pip не распознано как имя командлета" при попытке установить пакет с помощью pip

Tags: python, windows, pip

Учусь писать телеграм-ботов (для личных целей, не для продаж).

Хочу установить библиотеку `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` в терминале.

Выдаёт ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: В ошибке сказано, что команда `pip` не найдена. Вы уверены в том, что у вас в системе установлена программа `pip`?

Comment: Нет а где установить pip?

Comment: pip в path добавлен?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/#get-pip-py